# Rotating frame of reference, changing scale of angle calculations

Tags: python, geometry

I have wasted an embarrassing amount of time writing a function that takes two cartesian coordinates `origin` and `target`, and specifying the angle of the arrow pointing from `origin` to `target` in a `[0,360)` scale  where zero-degrees is the arrow pointing straight up.

The default python `atan2()` will give me  a `(-180,180]` with the zero-degrees arrow pointing right.

I can get the angle converted to a [0,360) scale,  but I cannot find a clean-looking way to change the 0-degree reference from being vector pointing right to the vector pointing up.   I made examples to show the evolution of the calculation and how it deviates from what I want.

```
def measure_angle_standard(origin, target):
    x = target[0]-origin[0]
    y = target[1]-origin[1]

    #angle relative to X axis going clockwise-positive
    angle_degrees =  math.degrees(math.atan2(y,x))
    return angle_degrees


def measure_angle_0_360(origin, target):
    x = target[0]-origin[0]
    y = target[1]-origin[1]

    #angle relative to X axis going clockwise-positive
    angle_degrees =  math.degrees(math.atan2(y,x))
    angle_degrees =      (angle_degrees + 360) % 360  
    return angle_degrees

def measure_angle_up_is_zero(origin, target):
    x = target[0]-origin[0]
    y = target[1]-origin[1]

    #angle relative to X axis going clockwise-positive
    angle_degrees =  math.degrees(math.atan2(y,x))
    #angle_degrees = angle_degrees -90 # this is wrong!
    angle_degrees =      (angle_degrees + 360) % 360  
    angle_degrees = (angle_degrees - 90) % 180   # this is also wrong!
    return angle_degrees


for v in [measure_angle_standard,  measure_angle_0_360, measure_angle_up_is_zero ]:
    print(f"\n\n {v}")
    print("up slightly right", round(v( (5,5), (5.1,2)),1),  " s/b tiny positive angle") #should be tiny positive angle
    print("point up ", v( (5,5), (5,2)), " s/b 0" )  #should be zero
    print("up slightly left ", round(v( (5,5), (4.9,2)),1), " s/b ~359 degrees") #should be almost 360

    print("point right ", v( (5,5), (9,5)), " s/b 90")  #should be 90
    print("point left ", v( (5,5), (1,5)), " s/b 270") #should be 270
    print("point down ", v( (5,5), (5,8)), " s/b 180") #should be 180
```

I don't see how to cleanly get the final rotation in a non-gross way.

(Before someone flags this message as a duplicate,  I've read dozens of similar questions here, and most of them are half-formed questions answered with code-golf fragment-incantations.  I am not interested to just randomly try hacks until I get something that works.  Often these answers fail on teh margin 0, 360, etc.)

```
 <function measure_angle_standard at 0x7fecda0947b8>
up slightly right -88.1  s/b tiny positive angle
point up  -90.0  s/b 0
up slightly left  -91.9  s/b ~359 degrees
point right  0.0  s/b 90
point left  180.0  s/b 270
point down  90.0  s/b 180


 <function measure_angle_0_360 at 0x7fecda040730>
up slightly right 271.9  s/b tiny positive angle
point up  270.0  s/b 0
up slightly left  268.1  s/b ~359 degrees
point right  0.0  s/b 90
point left  180.0  s/b 270
point down  90.0  s/b 180


 <function measure_angle_up_is_zero at 0x7fecda0940d0>
up slightly right 1.9  s/b tiny positive angle
point up  0.0  s/b 0
up slightly left  178.1  s/b ~359 degrees
point right  90.0  s/b 90
point left  90.0  s/b 270
point down  0.0  s/b 180
```

Answer (score 0):

I shift it with `math.p1/2` radians before i convert to degrees.

```
def measure_angle_up_is_zero(origin, target):
    x = target[0]-origin[0]
    y = target[1]-origin[1]

    #angle relative to Y axis going clockwise-positive
    angle_degrees =  math.degrees(math.atan2(y,x)+ (math.pi/2.0)) 
    angle_degrees =      (angle_degrees + 360) % 360  
    return angle_degrees
```

That gives me the answer I want:

```
 <function measure_angle_up_is_zero at 0x7fecda243400>
up slightly right 1.9  s/b tiny positive angle
point up  0.0  s/b 0
up slightly left  358.1  s/b ~359 degrees
slightly above right 88.56790381583534  s/b ~89
point right  90.0  s/b 90
slightly below right 91.43209618416466  s/b ~91
point left  270.0  s/b 270
point down  180.0  s/b 180
```